# How to resize input similar to Stack O for multi select list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create similar functionality to Stack Overflow's Tags input box. I would like my text input box (the aquamarine one) to resize dynamically. For example, when the page first loads the input should take up 100% of the area. When the user types and then selects a country option the input should take up less space horizontally. How can I make the input resize dynamically and offer a smooth user experience?

Here is my Javascript, CSS, and HTML. Feel free to comment on any of the code.

```js
        var selectedCatString = "";
        var totalSelected = 0;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // hide the cat list.
            $("#mtCategories").invisible();
            $('#mtResultDivArea').hide();

            // Display selected tags. Needed when editing.
            CreateSelectedTags("#mtCategories");

            $(document).click(function () {
                $('#mtResultDivArea').hide();
            });

            // When mtSearchArea is clicked place focus on the input.
            $('body').on('click', '#mtSearchArea', function () {
                $('#mtSearchInput').focus();
                $('#mtSearchArea').addClass("mtfocus");
            });

            //$('#mtSearchInput').focus(function () {
            //    $('#mtSearchArea').addClass("mtfocus");
            //});

            // Close/hide the mtResultDivArea.
            $('body').on('click', '.mtResultDivHide', function () {
                $('#mtResultDivArea').hide();
                $('#mtSearchInput').focus();
            });

            $('#mtSearchInput').keyup(function () {

                var resultDivString = "";
                var valueToSearch = $('#mtSearchInput').val();
                var listText = "";

                // Search after more than 1 character is entered
                if (valueToSearch.length > 1) {
                    // Instruction
                    resultDivString += "<div class=\"mtCatResultInstr\">";
                    resultDivString += "Select one or more option below.";
                        resultDivString += "<div class=\"mtResultDivHide\">";
                        resultDivString += "&#x2716;";
                        resultDivString += "</div>";
                    resultDivString += "</div>";
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------
                    var found = $('#mtCategories option').filter(function () {
                        listText = $(this).text();
                        // \\b matches words that begin with. \\b' + valueToSearch + \\b' sometimes does not work. Perhaps because there are no spaces before or after value so no boundary defined.
                        // To search for characters anywhere in a string remove the '\\b'
                        var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + valueToSearch, 'i');

                        if (listText.search(regex) > -1) {
                            // Create row with matching option
                            resultDivString += "<div class=\"mtCatResultRow\" id=\"" + $(this).val() + "\" txt=\"" + $(this).text() + "\">";
                            resultDivString += $(this).text();
                            resultDivString += "</div>";
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    });

                    if (found.length == 0) {
                        // Text not found
                        resultDivString = "<div class=\"mtCatResultInstr\">";
                        resultDivString += "Nothing found. Try another name.";
                        resultDivString += "<div class=\"mtResultDivHide\">";
                        resultDivString += "&#x2716;";
                        resultDivString += "</div>";
                        resultDivString += "</div>";
                    }

                    $('#mtResultDivArea').show();
                    $('#mtResultDivArea').html(resultDivString);
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------
                }

            });

            // When a category/tag is picked from the dynamic autocomplete div of options.
            $('body').on('click', '.mtCatResultRow', function () {
                event.stopPropagation(); // To prevent the click from closing the results div.
                var idval = $(this).attr("id");
                var textval = $(this).attr("txt"); // Not needed for now
                $('#mtSearchInput').focus();
                SelectDeselectItem("mtCategories", idval);
            });

            // When the X is clicked to remove the selected category/tag.
            $('body').on('click', '.mtSelectedOptionRemove', function () {
                event.stopPropagation(); // To prevent the click from closing the legendcodediv.
                var idval = $(this).attr("id");
                SelectDeselectItem("mtCategories", idval);
            });

        });
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        function SelectDeselectItem(strlist, strval) {
            var listname = "#" + strlist;
            var isValueSelected = $(listname + ' option[value="' + strval + '"]').prop('selected');
            $('#mtSearchInput').val(""); // Clear the input box when a selection is made

            if (isValueSelected == false) {
                if (totalSelected >= 8) {
                    alert("You can only select up to 8 categories. Remove some of the selected categories or add an additional post.");
                } else {
                    // Select the item
                    $(listname + ' option[value="' + strval + '"]').prop('selected', true);
                }

            } else {
                // Unselect the item.
                $(listname + ' option[value="' + strval + '"]').prop('selected', false);
            }

            CreateSelectedTags(listname);
        }

        jQuery.fn.visible = function () {
            return this.css('visibility', 'visible');
        };

        jQuery.fn.invisible = function () {
            return this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        };

        function CreateSelectedTags(strlist) {
            selectedCatString = "";
            totalSelected = 0;
            // Loop through list to determine what is selected.
            $(strlist + ' option:selected').each(function () {
                //alert($(this).text() + ' : ' + $(this).val());
                selectedCatString += "<div class=\"mtSelectedOptionBox\">";
                selectedCatString += "<div class=\"mtSelectedOption\">" + $(this).text() + "</div>";
                selectedCatString += "<div class=\"mtSelectedOptionRemove\" id=\"" + $(this).val() + "\" title=\"Click to remove.\">&#x2716;</div>";
                selectedCatString += "</div>";
                totalSelected++;
            });

            $('#mtSelectedOptionsArea').html(selectedCatString);
           
        }
```

```css
        [placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease; 
          opacity: 0;
        }

        .mtfocus {
         border: 2px solid #AA88FF;
         background-color: #FFEEAA;
        }

        #mtCatContainerDiv{
            /*background-color:#FFFFCC;
            border:1px dotted #999;*/
            width: 600px;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:12px;
        }

        
        #mtSearchArea{
            padding:4px;
            margin-top:6px;
            min-height:30px;
            background-color:#FFF;
            border:1px solid #CCC;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

       #mtResultDivArea{
            width:300px;
            position:absolute;
            z-index:99;
            background-color:#EEE;
            border-top:1px solid #999;
            border-left:5px solid #999;
            border-right:5px solid #999;
            border-bottom:4px solid #999;
        }

        #mtSearchInput{
            padding:5px;
            max-width:100px;
            border:none;
            background-color:aquamarine; 
        }

        #mtSearchInput::-ms-clear {
          width : 0;
          height: 0;
        }

        #mtSearchInput:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        .mtSelectedOptionBox{
            margin:4px;
            padding:4px;
            display: inline-block;
            color:#333;
            background-color:#ffd800;
        }

       .mtSelectedOption{
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .mtSelectedOptionRemove{
            cursor:pointer;
            padding:3px;
            font-size:11px;
            margin-left:4px;
            display: inline-block;
            color:#333;
        }

        .mtSelectedOptionRemove:hover {
            background-color:#dcbf1e;
        }


        #mtCategories{
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
        }

        .mtDropdownArea{
            /*background-color:#bcf787;*/
            height:2px;
        }

        .mtCatResultInstr{
            font-weight:bold;
            padding:5px 5px 8px 5px;
            color:white;
            background-color:#999;
            border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC;
        }

        .mtResultDivHide{
            float:right;
            cursor:pointer;
            padding:3px;
            font-size:11px;
            color:white;
            background-color:#838383;
        }

        .mtCatResultRow{
            cursor:pointer;
            padding:5px;
            border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC;
        }

        .mtCatResultRow:hover{
            background-color:#ffd800;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mtCatContainerDiv">

            <p><strong>Enter a country name below:</strong></p>

            <div id="mtSearchArea"><span id="mtSelectedOptionsArea"></span> <input id="mtSearchInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter country" /></div>
            
            <div id="mtResultDivArea"></div>

            <p class="mtDropdownArea">

                 <select id="mtCategories" class="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple" name="mtCategories">
                    <option value="Afghan">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="Alby">Albania</option>
                    <option value="Algy">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="And">Andorra</option>
                    <option value="Ang">Angola</option>
                    <option value="Ant">Antigua &amp; Deps</option>
                    <option value="Arg">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="Arm">Armenia</option>
                    <option value="Aust">Australia</option>
                    <option value="Austr">Austria</option>
                    <option value="Azer">Azerbaijan</option>
                    <option value="Baha">Bahamas</option>
                    <option value="Bah">Bahrain</option>
                    <option value="Bang">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                    <option value="Bosnia Herzegovina">Bosnia Herzegovina</option>
                    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                    <option value="Burkina">Burkina</option>
                    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                    <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                    <option value="Central African Rep">Central African Rep</option>
                    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                    <option value="China">China</option>
                    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                    <option value="Congo {Democratic Rep}">Congo {Democratic Rep}</option>
                    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                    <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
                    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                    <option value="France">France</option>
                    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                    <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                    <option value="Hrvatska">Hrvatska</option>
                    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
                    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                    <option value="Ireland {Republic}">Ireland {Republic}</option>
                    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                    <option value="Ivory Coast">Ivory Coast</option>
                    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                    <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                    <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                    <option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
                    <option value="Korea South">Korea South</option>
                    <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
                    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                    <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                    <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
                    <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                    <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
                    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                    <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                    <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                    <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
                    <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                    <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                    <option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
                    <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
                    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                    <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
                    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                    <option value="Myanmar, {Burma}">Myanmar, {Burma}</option>
                    <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                    <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                    <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                    <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                    <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                    <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                    <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                    <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                    <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                    <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                    <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                    <option value="St Kitts &amp; Nevis">St Kitts &amp; Nevis</option>
                    <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
                    <option value="Saint Vincent &amp; the Grenadines">Saint Vincent &amp; the Grenadines</option>
                    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                    <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                    <option value="Sao Tome &amp; Principe">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
                    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                    <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                    <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                    <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                    <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                    <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                    <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                    <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                    <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                    <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
                    <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                    <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                    <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
                    <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                    <option value="Trinidad &amp; Tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
                    <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                    <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                    <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                    <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                    <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                    <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                    <option value="Vatican City">Vatican City</option>
                    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                    <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                    <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                </select>
            </p>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First 100% as usually, as and when user selects one option get the Word-Count or Char-Count and give appropriate width to the element. you can add transition on width for smoothness.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try that way.